# Web project dependency pojos, web deployment

Tags: spring, maven-2

I have 3 maven projects:
1 - common pojos project
2 - web project
3 - java client project

web and java project uses same pojos from common project, have dependency on 1 project

I added to web build path common pojos project, 
but when I deploy web project to server, no pojo classes exceptions....

My question is how can I configure it to get my pojos classes deployed with all web project ?
(it will be fantastic, If you have some online examples for this)
Tnx.

Comment: Please visit [How To Create A Web Application Project With Maven](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/)

Comment: I have maven projects, My question was how to create maven project with dependencies !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your 3 project are maven projects and the dependencies are set right then maven will automatically package all the dependencies into the war.

commons pojos is a jar project
web project is a war project which depends on commons pojos project. Unless the dependency **scope** is not **provided** the jar will be packaged in the war.

You can verify the same by opening the war file as see if the commons pojos jar is present and the jar has the required classes.

Comment: If its right then it should work. Without the maven config files and information confirmation based on my answer I can't help you.